# How to mask/hide URL params on and off with javascript without refresh?

Tags: javascript

As the question states, how do you hide/unhide/mask URL query parameters in javascript? This site appears to be able to do something like it:

```
http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/#!
```

(Check the  "Share it! If checked, the option values will be stored in the URL so that you can easily share your settings.")

Say I have the following URL...

```
http://localhost/?var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3
```

How do I hide just the var2 and var3 portion such that the URL is:

```
http://localhost/?var1=value1
```

(WIth a click of a link on the page to toggle the GET variable in and out of the page without refreshing it.)

Comment: I care about hiding/masking the GET parameters with a click of a link, not retrieving them.

Comment: If you don't want the users know the parameters ,right?
How about encode the parameters,using base64 or some other methods to encode them.

Comment: I just want the user to be able to hide and unhide params without refreshing the page like the site I linked to depicts. I could care less about parameter encodings unless that is somehow part of the method used by the website I linked to show and hide parameters in the URL with the click of the share checkbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `replaceState`:

```
if(history.replaceState) history.replaceState({}, "", "/");
```

Where / is the path you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden form with a POST method, fill the two params to `<input type="hidden">` and submit. All with JS.